# How to download Apple Keynotes?

Tags: download, streaming, iwork-keynote

I've tried the usual suspects like WellGet, NetXfer, wget with some referrer forgery and so on, but I never succeeded.

So the problem is, I want to download the keynotes from Apple, like the current one in HD if available instead of relying on (let's call them) third party sources.

http://www.apple.com/apple-events/

Can somebody help me? Thank you.

PS: Available OSs, Windows, Linux
PPS: I was unable to check iTunes because I don't use that. But if it is available there, please point it out and also the Quality/Resolution if given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Apple Keynotes are available on iTunes: Podcasts>Technology>Tech News>Apple Inc. The quality is the same as the stream.

Comment: And if you don't use iTunes, the podcast URL is http://www.apple.com/podcasts/apple_keynotes/apple_keynotes.xml
They usually get pushed later on in the day of the event.

Comment: @alexandru Oh wow! I didn't know about that! That looks useful, thanks! Wish I could tick that answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the urls into [jDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/). There you get the .mov files with the stream urls (Open them with notepad). But by now I don't figured out yet how to download these. But maybe that helps you.